# Map a 3D plot into plane

Tags: plotting

I have a 3D plot like:

```
Ds=
1 - I ((0.602499 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I si + sr)])/(
    0.550556-I si - sr) + (
    0.101418 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I si + sr)])/(
    1.17669-I si - sr) + (
    5.66507 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I si + sr)])/(
    2.23017-I si - sr) + (
    0.920849 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I si + sr)])/(
    3.18056-I si - sr) + (1/(64 \[Pi]))
    Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(
      I si + sr)] (-1365.06 + 
       1/(-0.075076 + I si + sr)
         4 (30.8579 Log[1 + 0.31441 (-0.075076 + I si + sr)] + 
          189.838 Log[1 + 0.448396 (-0.075076 + I si + sr)] + 
          3.39856 Log[1 + 0.849842 (-0.075076 + I si + sr)] + 
          20.1899 Log[1 + 1.81635 (-0.075076 + I si + sr)])));

Plot3D[Re[Ds], {sr, -.3, .3}, {si, -0.3, .3}]
```

I want to draw a 2D plot in which `Re[Ds]` is a vertical axes and sr is a horizontal one.
Or its better to say I want to view my 3D plot in certain planes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can add an appropriate `RegionFunction` in `Plot3D`, e.g. assuming a `xz-plane` 
where `y == 2 x + 1` :

```
Plot3D[ Sin[ x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 x - y < 0], Filling -> Bottom,
        FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.6]], PlotPoints -> 150, BoxRatios -> {6, 8, 2}]
```

[image]

Assuming one wants a `2D` plot, we have to add a rule linking `y` nad `x`, e.g. `y -> 2x + 1`, thus:

```
Plot[ Sin[x + y^2] //. y -> 2 x + 1, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Bottom, 
      FillingStyle -> Directive[ Red, Opacity[0.5]], AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

**Edit**

This queston was edited a few times and now it is quite different from the original one. 
Let's define `Ds` this way calling it `S` :

```
S[ x_, y_] := 1 - I ((0.602499 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I  y + x)])/(0.550556 - I y - x ) 
            + ( 0.101418 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I  y + x)])/(1.17669 - I y - x ) 
            + ( 5.66507 Sqrt[1 - 0.075076/(I  y + x)])/(2.23017 - I y - x ) 
            + ( 0.920849 Sqrt[ 1 - 0.075076/(I y + x)])/( 3.18056 - I y - x ) 
            + (1/(64 Pi)) Sqrt[ 1 - 0.075076/(I y + x)] (-1365.06 + 1/(-0.075076 + I y + x)
              4 (   30.8579 Log[ 1 + 0.31441 (-0.075076 + I y + x)]
                  + 189.838 Log[ 1 + 0.448396 (-0.075076 + I y + x)]
                  + 3.39856 Log[ 1 + 0.849842 (-0.075076 + I y + x)] 
                  + 20.1899 Log[ 1 + 1.81635 (-0.075076 + I y + x)] )))
```

now we can plot it in `3D` as a function over a domain in the complex plane :

```
Plot3D[ Re[ S[ x, y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -0.5, .2}, PlotPoints -> 100, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

or restricting `S` to a submanifold (in this case to a line `y == 2 x + 1`)  :

```
 Plot[ Re[ S[ x, 2 x + 1]], {x, -.48, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Axis, 
                                    FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]] ]
```

[image]

we can use also `Show` and `ParametricPlot3D` :

```
Show[
      ParametricPlot3D[{ x, 2 x + 1 - y, Re[S[x, y]]},
                         {x, -.5, 0}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.46], PlotPoints -> 100], 
      Plot3D[ Re[ S[ x, 2 x + 1]], {x, -.5, 0}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False,
              Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]],

              BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but I want mathematica to draw a 2D plot( a plane) which one axes is x and another is z.

Comment: So update your question !

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Ok. I have the following plot:                             Plot3D[Re[Ds], {sr, -.3, .3}, {si, -0.3, .3}]              in which Ds is a complicated complex function of sr and si. Now I want to see Re[Ds] versus sr in a plane.

Comment: I wrote Ds in my question.

Comment: @soodeh Update your question once more including an example of `Ds`.  And finally decide whether you want a `2D` plot or `3D` plot.

Comment: I updated it, I want a 2D plot.

Comment: sorry. But my question is clear for myself. I have a function of 2 variables. I can Plot it in 3 dimension , But I want to draw a plot of my function versus one of the variables in 2 dimension.

Comment: @soodeh Why don't you register your account to benefit more from this site ?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
Plot[Table[Re[Ds], {si, Range[-.3, .3, .1]}], {sr, -.3, .3}, 
 Evaluated -> True, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

or

```
plt1 = Plot3D[Re[Ds], {sr, -.3, .3}, {si, -0.3, .3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> None];
mesh = Range[-.3, .3, .1];
plt2 = ParametricPlot3D[{sr, #, Re[Ds] /. si -> #} & /@ 
    mesh, {sr, -.3, .3}, Evaluated -> True, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[y]], 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    FaceGrids -> {{{-1, 0, 0}, {mesh, None}}, 
     {{1, 0, 0}, {mesh, None}}, 
     {{0, 0, -1}, {None, mesh}}, 
     {{0, 0, 1}, {None, mesh}}},
    PlotRangePadding -> 0];
 Show[plt2, plt1]
```

[image]