# Integrating over a region without singularity gives an error indicating the function has singularity in that region

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0.0 or earlier and fixed in 8.0.4**

---

I have the following 2D region over which I want to integrate a function:

```
r1  = Sqrt[mη^2 + (Sqrt[w1^2 - mπ^2] + Sqrt[w2^2 - mπ^2])^2] // Expand;
r2  = Sqrt[mη^2 + (Sqrt[w1^2 - mπ^2] - Sqrt[w2^2 - mπ^2])^2] // Expand;
mη  = 0.547;
mηp = 0.958;
mπ  = 0.137;

RegionPlot[mηp - w1 - w2 < Re[r1] && mηp - w1 - w2 > Re[r2], 
   {w1, .1, .25}, {w2, .1, .25}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue, FrameLabel -> {"w1", "w2"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I want to integrate the following function over this region:

```
function[w1_, w2_]=Abs[1.05133+ (6.16152 (0.656093- 1.916 w1 - 1.916 w2)
    (0.958- 1. w1 - 1. w2))/(0.921055- 1.916 w1 - 1.916 w2) - 
    (10.1147 (0.656093- 1.916 w1 - 1.916 w2) (0.958- 1. w1 - 1. w2))/
    (1.57895- 1.916 w1 - 1.916 w2) - 55.0594 (-((0.479 w1 (-0.618555 + 1.916 w1))/
    (0.0307393+ 1.916 w1)) - ( 0.479 w2 (-0.618555 + 1.916 w2))/(0.0307393+ 1.916 w2))]^2
```

When I plot the function it doesn't have any singularity:

```
Plot3D[function[w1,w2],{w1, 0.137, 0.2445}, {w2, 0.137, 0.2445}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{w1, w2, z}, mηp - w1 - w2 < Re[r1] && mηp - w1 - w2 > Re[r2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I use the following command:

```
NIntegrate[function[w1,w2] Boole[Re[r2]< mηp - w1 - w2 <  
   Re[r1]], {w1, 0.137, 0.2445}, {w2, 0.137, 0.2445}]
```

*Mathematica* says it has a singularity. Why?

Comment: Mma is not saying it has a singularity: `Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the \
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small`

Comment: what should I do to solve this problem? Because I know this integral should have an answer about 0.0000872

Comment: I don't know am I right or not but it seems that over this region the shape of the function is common(It doesn't have singularity, It is not highly osccillating or...), then what is the problem? With Boole does it calculate the function in the region only? Because I know out of this region function has singularity.

Comment: @soodeh What's the point of defining `function = Abs[...]^2` ? Why not  `function = (...)^2` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks You are right. I can omit it.

Comment: @soodeh In this case the integral is done quickly and I get 0.161934.

Comment: But still it has an error:NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. ....

Comment: @soodeh I'm on Mathematica 8.0.4 and after removing the `Abs` I don't get any error/warning.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Nice! I get error on Mathematica 8.0.0.

Comment: @soodeh Please, consider registering your account. Then e.g. this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/map-a-3d-plot-into-plane will be yours and reputation you'll gain will allow you do more on this site.

Comment: @soodeh It seems that you have two unregistered accounts, both under the name Soodeh. Is that true? Could you register one of them so that we can merge the accounts?

Comment: @soodeh, I get the same answer as does b.gatessucks. I am also in version 8.0.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems the OP's problem was caused by a bug in V8.0.0 that was fixed by V8.0.4.

Comment: @m_goldberg we don't usually close questions caused by Mathematica bugs. When confirmed they get the bugs tag and a header indicating introduction and fix versions.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. I'm embarrassed by the violation of protocol that you point out. I'm willing to reopen this, but I'd still like to get it off the unanswered question list. Would a community wiki answer pointing out the bug and its correction be acceptable to the community (get a least one up-vote), do you think?

Comment: @m_goldberg If you add an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: I voting to reopen this question because as Sjoerd has pointed out it should be marked as a bug report and then get a confirming answer. I will write one as a CW answer.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. Calling in your promise to up-vote the community wiki answer I have posted.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok. Done

Answer (score 4):

The comments show that this is a bug in V8.0.0. b.gatessucks and Fred Kline confirm was fixed in V8.0.4.